# Draw a figure with two arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the attached figure, however, I don't know how to add two arrows and how to put the name on the arrow. Could you help me with that? Thank you in advance.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.7em, minimum width=2em},
blockev/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.8cm, minimum width=1.8cm},
blocksmallev/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.8cm, minimum width=1.2cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
arr/.style = {-Stealth},
\node [blockev, minimum height =2.5cm, minimum width=3.5cm, label={[above, very thick, font = \large]}](celll) at (-1.26,-2.74){} ;

\node[input, name = input, font = \normalsize] (input){};
\node[blockev, right = 0.4cm of input,  font = \normalsize] (feature) {\textbf{Feature} \textbf{extraction}};

\node[blocksmallev, left = 0.35cm of feature,  font = \normalsize] (segmen) {{\shortstack{\textbf{Segmentation}\\ \textbf{Module}}}};
\node[blocksmallev, fill = blue!50, left = 0.35cm of segmen,  font = \normalsize] (trigger) {{\shortstack{\textbf{LR }\\ \textbf{ Image}}}};

\node[blocksmallev, fill = blue!50, right = 0.55cm of feature,  font = \normalsize] (class) {{\shortstack{\textbf{Classification }\\ \textbf{ Module}}}};

\node[blocksmallev, fill = blue!50, right = 0.55cm of class,  font = \normalsize] (recon) {{\shortstack{\textbf{Reconstruction }\\ \textbf{ of each}}}};
\node[blocksmallev, fill = blue!50, right = 0.55cm of recon,  font = \normalsize] (aggre) {{\shortstack{\textbf{Aggregation }\\ \textbf{ of each}}}};

\node[blocksmallev, fill = blue!50, right = 0.55cm of aggre,  font = \normalsize] (sr) {{\shortstack{\textbf{SR IMAGE }\\ \textbf{ of each}}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reconstruction of image showed in given link in question:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc,
                positioning,
                shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 17mm,
arr/.style = {-Stealth},
arv/.style = {-, ultra thick, dotted, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=2mm},
box/.style = {draw, semithick, fill=#1, 
              minimum width=5em, minimum height=5.1\baselineskip,
              outer sep=0pt, align=center},
 fe/.style = {draw, semithick, fill=teal!30, 
              outer sep=0pt, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
              align=center},
lbl/.style = {auto, align=center, 
              font=\footnotesize\linespread{0.84}\selectfont, 
              name=#1},
 SA/.style = {single arrow, draw, semithick, 
              single arrow head extend=2mm, 
              minimum height=7mm, minimum width=7mm,
              outer sep=0pt},
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Stealth},
                        ]
\node (n1)  [fe, fill=none] {LR\\image};
\node (sa1) [SA, right=0pt of n1] {};
\node (n2)  [box=yellow!50, right=0pt of sa1]  
        {Segmentation\\ module};
%
\node (n3a) [fe, below right=0pt and 12mm of n2.north east]
        {Feature\\ extraction};
\node (n3b) [fe, above right=0pt and 12mm of n2.south east]
        {Feature\\ extraction};
%
\node (n4) [box=cyan!30, right=of n2 -| n3a.east]
        {Classification\\ Module};
\node (n5)  [box = red!50, right = of n4] 
        {Reconstruction\\ of each patch\\ using the best\\ models};
\node (sa2) [SA, right=0pt of n5] {};
\node (n6)  [box=yellow!50, right = 0pt of sa2]
        {Aggregation\\ Module};
\node (sa3) [SA, right=0pt of n6] {};
\node (n7)  [fe, fill=none, right = 0pt of sa3]
        {SR\\ image};
\draw   (n3a -| n2.east) edge node[lbl=pa] {Patch-1}   (n3a)
        (n3b -| n2.east) edge node[lbl=pb] {Patch-n}   (n3b)
        (n3a) edge node[lbl=fa] {Features}   (n3a -| n4.west)
        (n3b) edge node[lbl=fb] {Features}   (n3b -| n4.west)
        (n3a -| n4.east) 
            edge node[lbl=bma] {Best model\\ for Patch-1}   (n3a -| n5.west)
        (n3b -| n4.east) 
            edge node[lbl=bmb] {Best model\\ for Patch-n}   (n3b -| n5.west)
        ;
\draw   (pa)    edge [arv] (pb)
        (fa)    edge [arv] (fb)
        (bma)   edge [arv] (bmb)
        ; 

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, I give you a hint on what you can do to draw those two arrows from a node.

[image: two arrows from a node]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,
                        block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.7em, minimum width=2em},
                        blockev/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.8cm, minimum width=1.8cm},
                        blocksmallev/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.8cm, minimum width=2.5cm},
                        input/.style={coordinate},
                        arr/.style = {-Stealth},]
    
    
        \node[blocksmallev,text width=2.5cm,align=center] (segmen) {\textbf{Segmentation Module}};
        
        \node[blockev,right= of segmen] (feature) {\textbf{Feature extraction}};
        
        \def\shft{5}
        \draw [arr] ([yshift=\shft mm]segmen.east) -- ([yshift=\shft mm]feature.west) node[above,midway] {Patch-1};
        \draw [arr] ([yshift=-\shft mm]segmen.east) -- ([yshift=-\shft mm]feature.west) node[above,midway](patchn) {Patch-n};
        \node[above=-1mm of patchn]{\vdots};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used what you did in your code, even if the *Feature extraction* is in two boxes in the sketch.
You can play with `shft` to make some more space.

Now, there's still some work to do on your whole design and you may want to organize it a bit more. You can find many comparable designs here on TeX-SE that could inspire you.

### EDIT: HOW TO JOIN TWO BLOCKS

[image: with two blocks]

Here you have to play with anchors. I had to define another type of block, named `smallblock` and position the upper one on the right of `segmen.north east`, while attaching it to its `north west` anchor. That way the upper lines are aligned. Same with the lower one but to the south.

Then, to draw the arrows (and to draw them strictly horizontal), I had to make them start at the intersection of the east side of *segmen* and the horizontal position of *feature1*. This point coordinate is written `(segmen.east|-feature1)`. Then it's pointing to *feature1*.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows.meta,decorations, positioning, arrows.meta, calc, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,
                        block/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.7em, minimum width=2em},
                        smallblock/.style={draw, fill=olive!15, rectangle, minimum height=7.5mm, minimum width=2em},
                        blockev/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.8cm, minimum width=1.8cm},
                        blocksmallev/.style={draw, fill=blue!15, rectangle, minimum height=1.8cm, minimum width=2.5cm},
                        input/.style={coordinate},
                        arr/.style = {-Stealth},]
    
    
        \node[blocksmallev,text width=2.5cm,align=center] (segmen) {\textbf{Segmentation Module}};
        
        \node[smallblock,right= of segmen.north east,anchor=north west] (feature1) {\textbf{Feature extraction}};
        \node[smallblock,right= of segmen.south east,anchor=south west] (feature2) {\textbf{Feature extraction}};
        
        \def\shft{5}
        \draw [arr] (segmen.east|-feature1) -- (feature1) node[above,midway] {Patch-1};
        \draw [arr] (segmen.east|-feature2) -- (feature2) node[above,midway](patchn) {Patch-n};
        \node[above=-1mm of patchn]{\vdots};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @sebglav. Could you please tell me how to add two blocks right of segmentation block? like the attached figure.

Comment: It's done, Sir ;)

Comment: Thank you so much.